# Is this a new common pattern in Oracle Where exists ( Select NULL FROM...)?

Tags: oracle, sql-server, style

Years ago, it was common to write

```
where exists (Select * from some_table where some_condition)
```

Last year I noticed that many t-sql scripts switched to using the number 1 instead of the star

```
where exists (Select 1 from some_table where some_condition)
```

just on [SO I saw this  Oracle example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605948/delete-rows-using-sql-like-command-using-data-from-another-table/4606022#4606022)

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM ...
```

Is this a common  pattern with Oracle?
And which are the performance arguments to use something like this.

Comment: SO has a discussion of this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424212/performance-of-sql-exists-usage-variants

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: I would hope not!

Even the `SELECT 1` idiom may have outlived its usefulness, as database engines have advanced enough to recognize that you don't really want the rows, you just want to know if the rows exist. I've looked at execution plans in SQL 2005, and have generally seen these re-written as joins, even where `SELECT *` is used.

Answer (score 5):

In Oracle it doesn't matter performance wise.  You can even put 1/0 there and the statement won't return a divide by zero error because the expression isn't evaluated.

Comment: Does this need to be closed in favor of relying on the SO question? Is this one of those "migrate the SO to dba.SE"?